# Why is PHP not sending anything into MariaDB?

Tags: php, html

I apologize for the absurdly long code. The problem is that it does not send the code to the database. Nothing occurs and I receive no errors. The data isn't sent to the database. Is there a limit to how many columns you can add? I've done this with less and it worked, I don't know what the problem could be.

```
  <?php
  $connection = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","RS");
  if($connection->connect_error){
      die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $joindate = $_POST['joindate'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $languages = $_POST['languages'];
  $oldname = $_POST['oldname'];
  $fishing = $_POST['fishing'];
  $frontwebdev = $_POST['frontwebdev'];
  $backwebdev = $_POST['backwebdev'];
  $writing = $_POST['writing'];
  $programming = $_POST['programming'];
  $art = $_POST['art'];
  $se = $_POST['se'];
  $smm = $_POST['smm'];
  $testing = $_POST['testing'];
  $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];
  $availability = $_POST['availability'];
  $reliability = $_POST['reliability'];
  $avatar = $_POST['avatar'];
  if ($age == 0 or $age == '')  {
    $age = NULL;
  }
  if ($oldname == '')  {
    $age = NULL;
  }
  if ($fishing == 0 or $fishing == '')  {
    $fishing = NULL;
  }
  if ($frontwebdev == 0 or $frontwebdev == '')  {
    $frontwebdev = NULL;
  }
  if ($writing == 0 or $writing == '')  {
    $writing = NULL;
  }
  if ($frontwebdev == 0 or $frontwebdev == '')  {
    $frontwebdev = NULL;
  }
  if ($programming == 0 or $programming == '')  {
    $programming = NULL;
  }
  if ($frontwebdev == 0 or $frontwebdev == '')  {
    $frontwebdev = NULL;
  }
  if ($art == 0 or $art == '')  {
    $art = NULL;
  }
  if ($se == 0 or $se == '')  {
    $se = NULL;
  }
  if ($smm == 0 or $smm == '')  {
    $smm = NULL;
  }
  if ($testing == 0 or $testing == '')  {
    $testing = NULL;
  }
  if ($timezone == 0 or $timezone == '')  {
    $timezone = NULL;
  }
  if ($availability == 0 or $availability == '')  {
    $availability = NULL;
  }
  if ($reliability == 0 or $reliability == '')  {
    $reliability = NULL;
  }
  if ($avatar == 0 or $avatar == '')  {
    $avatar = NULL;
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo (username, joindate, age, languages, oldname, fishing, frontwebdev, backwebdev, writing, programming, art, se, smm, testing, timezone, availability, reliability, avatar) VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $joindate . "', '" . $age . "', '" . $languages . "', '" . $oldname . "', '" . $fishing . "', '" . $frontwebdev . "', '" . $backwebdev . "', '" . $writing . "', '" . $programming . "', '" . $art . "', '" . $se . "', '" . $smm . "', '" . $testing . "', '" . $timezone . "', '" . $availability . "', '" . $reliability . "', '" . $avatar . "';";
  mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
  }
  mysqli_close($connection);
  ?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" style="text-align: center;">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="username" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Required"><br /><br /><td>
</tr>
  <td>Join year</td><td><input type="text" name="joindate" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
<tr>
  <td>Age</td><td><input type="text" name="age" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Languages</td><td><input type="text" name="languages" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Old Name</td><td><input type="text" name="oldname" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fishing skill</td><td><input type="text" name="Fishing" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Front web dev skill</td><td><input type="text" name="frontwebdev" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Back web dev skill</td><td><input type="text" name="backwebdev" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Writing</td><td><input type="text" name="writing" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Programming</td><td><input type="text" name="programming" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Art</td><td><input type="text" name="art" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>SE</td><td><input type="text" name="se" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Social Media Management</td><td><input type="text" name="smm" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Testing</td><td><input type="text" name="testing" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Timezone</td><td><input type="text" name="timezone" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Availability</td><td><input type="text" name="availability" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Required"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Reliability</td><td><input type="text" name="reliability" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Required"><br /><br />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Url to avatar</td><td><input type="text" name="avatar" style="width: 400px; padding: 3px;" placeholder="Optional"><br /><br />
</tr>
</table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This url might help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: `@mysqli_connect` is very suspicious. Why did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute of your "Fishing skill" textbox is "Fishing" and your PHP code refers to `$_POST['fishing']`

Variable names (and array indexes like this one) are case sensitive so the value does not get set and it may prevent your insert query from completing. Correcting this may fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close `VALUES`'s bracket at the end of your SQL, not by semicolon ( '`;`')

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo 
          (username, joindate, age, languages, 
           oldname, fishing, frontwebdev, backwebdev, 
           writing, programming, art, se, smm, testing, 
           timezone, availability, reliability, avatar) 
        VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $joindate . "', 
                '" . $age . "', '" . $languages . "', 
                '" . $oldname . "', '" . $fishing . "', 
                '" . $frontwebdev . "', '" . $backwebdev . "', 
                '" . $writing . "', '" . $programming . "', 
                '" . $art . "', '" . $se . "', '" . $smm . "', 
                '" . $testing . "', '" . $timezone . "', 
                '" . $availability . "', '" . $reliability . "', 
                '" . $avatar . "')";

                                 ^
                                here
```